# Plotting a Box Plot for 'share' column using another categorical variable 'Day'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, boxplot

```
        shares    PC         Day
0.01    546.68  NaN         Weekend
0.02    695.34  27.193239   Weekend
0.03    768.00  10.449564   Weekend
0.04    809.56  5.411458    Weekend
0.05    837.45  3.445081    Weekend
0.06    865.34  3.330348    Weekend
0.07    893.00  3.196431    Weekend
0.08    917.00  2.687570    Weekend
0.90    6200.00 8.771930    Weekday
0.91    6700.00 8.064516    Weekday
0.92    7500.00 11.940299   Weekday
0.93    8300.00 10.666667   Weekday
0.94    9400.00 13.253012   Weekday
```

I need to create 2 box subplots for 'shares' column from the above dataframe using the categorical variable Day which has 2 values Weekday and Weekend.

1st Sub Plot will be for Shares across Weekdays and the 2nd Sub Plot will be for Shares across Weekends.

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work:

```
df.boxplot(column = ['Shares'],by='Day')
```

Comment: Where is this code even considering that the plot is on 'shares' column ?

Comment: ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1715                     warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1716                                   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1718         pre_doc = inner.__doc__
   1719         if pre_doc is None:

TypeError: boxplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Comment: Thank you. Made a minor change as indicated by Bart. 'columns' to 'column'

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment...This answer will work. Use column instead of columns, and in your case, lower case shares. I tested it.

```
df.boxplot(column = ['shares'],by='Day')
```